# Назывное + двусоставное, знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

> От него пахло старомодным одеколоном, а цвет лица указывал на недавние
>   контрастные компрессы от приличной барберии (которые сохранились здесь
>   и оказывают услуги по ежедневному бритью или же ухаживают за вашей
>   бородой). Профессиональная укладка. Изящный тёмно-синий клубный
>   пиджак, **строгий галстук и белоснежный платок сиял в своём
>   кармашке**.

Comment: А что вас именно интересует - знаки препинания а выделенном предложении?

Comment: Ну да. Пиджак-галстук, а платок, видите ли, сиял.

Comment: Да,  действительно. Но здесь надо говорить не о знаках, а о структуре. Может, так? .... и сияющий белоснежный платок в своем кармашке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Изящный тёмно-синий клубный пиджак, строгий галстук и белоснежный платок, **сияющий в своём кармашке**.*

Если платок нужно как-то выделить, желательно добавить  какой-нибудь информации, например:

(2)*Изящный тёмно-синий клубный пиджак, строгий галстук. **И белоснежный платок — он, как и ожидалось, сиял в своём кармашке.***

Comment: Sharon,  отлично!